# Select row from table from each schema

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to select the row from DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK table from each schema with a given LIKE name. i.e. ...LIKE 'myschemaprefix%';

I would like something other than UNIONS as I have a large number of users.

```
SELECT 'MySchema1' as SCHEMA_NAME, LOCKED, LOCKGRANTED, LOCKEDBY FROM MySchema1.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
UNION
SELECT 'MySchema2' as SCHEMA_NAME, LOCKED, LOCKGRANTED, LOCKEDBY FROM MySchema1.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK;
```

I attacked the problem using procedure to capture the names of all my schemas.

```
SET serveroutput ON
BEGIN
  FOR item IN (
    SELECT USERNAME FROM dba_users WHERE USERNAME LIKE 'MySchemaPrefix%'
  ) LOOP

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE
      (item.username||'.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK');
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

What I need is a SELECT within the loop that uses the output value to grab any rows where the LOCKED = 1;

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may fetch the required data

```
SET serveroutput ON
declare
  cur_locks sys_refcursor; -- cursor to fetch lock info

  -- variables to store data from a row of lock info
  v_locked number;
  v_lock_granted varchar2(30);
  v_locked_by varchar2(30);

BEGIN
  FOR item IN (
    SELECT USERNAME FROM dba_users WHERE USERNAME LIKE 'MySchemaPrefix%'
  ) LOOP

      OPEN cur_locks FOR
        'SELECT LOCKED, LOCKGRANTED, ' ||
        ' LOCKEDBY FROM '  || item.USERNAME  || '.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK '
        || ' WHERE LOCKED = 1 ';       

      -- loop to fetch and print
      LOOP
        fetch cur_locks into 
         v_locked, v_lock_granted, v_locked_by;
        EXIT WHEN cur_locks%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line(
          item.USERNAME ||','||
          v_locked ||','||
          v_lock_granted ||','||
          v_locked_by
        );
      end loop;

      close cur_locks;

    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE
      --(item.username||'.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK');
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```